# How do I restrict the user from accessing the static html files in a ExpressJS/NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, url-routing

Is there any way to detect the request URL of the user and reroute to a particular error page, like for example,
I want all the routes to any HTML file (*.html), kind of detect it and want it to be rerouted to an Error page. Also hide it from the user to view it.

P.S: Using Express 4 and Latest Node.JS version.

```
app.get('/', function(req,res){
    if(req.is('text/html') == true){
        res.redirect('/login');
    }
```

This doesn't seem to work, I think I am missing the parament in the get request.

Please guide. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Just put your snippet before your `app.use(express.static(...));` it should work.

Comment: Why are you hosting the files under a static route in the first place if you don't want people to access them?

Comment: @Quentin Where should I put them then?

Comment: @Chinya_DotA — You could just delete them. (It's very hard to give a useful suggestion about where to put files when you don't know what they are for,  you've only told us what they are *not* for).

Comment: @Quentin Yea, I basically want to hide all my views(html), css, js from Users directly trying to access them instead navigate through proper express routes.

Comment: So the HTML files are actually template files? Create a template directory and keep them there.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that you have the text `html` in your url, and whenever this is the case you want to route it to `login`. Try following:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    if ((req.path.indexOf('html') >= 0)) {
        res.redirect('/login');
    } 
});
```

It checks your url path, and if it detects `html` it will redirect to `login`

Comment: Or with Regex in the route: `app.use(/html$/, function...)`